# How to set a define inside other define

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I'm developing a web application in jboss, seam, richfaces.

I'm using a template(xhtml) as master page of all others and there i set two insert tags. `<ui:insert name="head"/>`
`<ui:insert name="body"/>`

The problem is that in pages that use this master page as template, the `<ui:define name="head">...</ui:define>` must be defined inside the `<ui:define name="body">...</ui:define>`.

> How can i do this?

Basically, what i want is to do the following:

> `<ui:define name="body">... <ui:define name="head"> <meta name="title" content="#{something.title}" /> </ui:define> ...</ui:define>`

the master page must return :  `<meta name="title" content="#{something.title}" />` on the `<ui:insert name="head"/>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you have to nest ui:define tags? Chances are, you only think you do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think facelets work like that. It compiles and reads the template.

So I think you can just define how many definitions you want and dont care about nesting.

ie:

```
//In your template.xhtml
<ui:insert name="outer">
    BLA BLA BLA
    <ui:insert name="inner"/>
    BLA BLA BLA
</ui:insert>
```

And when you want to use this template simply:

```
 <ui:define name="outer">
    Here you can overwrite outer (This will probably overwrite inner, not sure, you need to test it)
 </ui:define>

 <ui:define name="inner">
    Or you can ONLY overwrite inner here if you want
 </ui:define>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ui:param>` in order to define `content` on each page. For example

in the template:

```
<meta name="title" content="#{titleParam}" />
```

in the page that uses the template:

```
<ui:param name="titleParam" value="customValueForThisPage" />
```

Comment: Hi Bozho, thanks for your reply.

Unfortunately, <ui:param> value it's not recognised on the template page when defined on the page that uses template, inside a define tag :(

Comment: use it outside the define tag. It is working perfectly in my current application.

Comment: Yes, works outside the define tag. But i need the information inside the define tag to fulfil ui:parameter value :s